# ArcMap printing the map problem

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, printing

I have created the map with some point and line layers. When I print this map, some points and lines of the map looks like shifted from their original locations. The print preview doesn't show any problems. The view of the map on the screen also looks ok. Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: There's many ways to print a map.  What are the precise steps that you performed to print yours?  What happens when you use the same steps but at the end print to PDF instead of to paper?  Please [edit] your question to provide more details.

Comment: The problem appears when printing to paper only. Exporting the map to PDF or other format and after that printing it doesn't cause any problems.

Answer (score 2):

sounds like it may be a printer driver issue. have you tried printing to a different printer as well as PDF? And if PDF works, then one solution could be to create PDF then send the PDF to the printer.